# PHP get data using JSON

Tags: php, json

I am currently trying to localise my website and all the data is going to be stored in JSON file. So i want to know how to get the data using php

**This is my sample JSON file/data**

```
{
  "en-us": {
    "registration": {
      "INVALID_USERNAME": "your username is taken",
      "INVALID_PASSWORD": "your password is not strong",
      "INVALID_EMAIL": "your email is invalid"
    },
    "login": {
      "INVALID_USERNAME": "please enter your username",
      "INVALID_PASSWORD": "please enter your password",
      "INVALID_LOGIN": "username or password is wrong"
    }
  }
}
```

now how do i get the value INVALID_USERNAME from the **registration** section?
I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("en-us.json")); //file containing the json data above
echo $obj->{'INVALID_USERNAME'};
```

Sorry i am a newbie to php and JSON, thanks for your help in advance,
Vidhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("en-us.json")); //file containing the json data above

echo $obj->{'en-us'}->{'registration'}->{'INVALID_USERNAME'};
```

Answer (score 1):

As a solution to your problem please try executing below code snippet

```
<?php
 $json_content=file_get_contents("en-us.json");
 $json_array=json_decode($json_content,true);
 if(!empty($json_array))
 {
    echo $json_array['en-us']['registration']['INVALID_USERNAME'];
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in doing:

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("en-us.json"));
```

To get `INVALID_USERNAME` you need to do:

```
$obj->en_us->registration->INVALID_USERNAME
```

This is because `INVALID_USERNAME` is a property within the object `registration`, which is a property under the object `en_us`.